# SMTP DNS Validation with multiple mail servers behind multiple Public IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, email-server, ptr-record

I know when a Mail server receives an e-mail, it performs a "DNS 3 way check" (I think this is also sometimes called [FCrDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS)) as a simply test against spammers.  The way I understand it to work is as follows:

Starting with the Source IP of the incoming mail (taken from the actual IP Packet):

1. Reverse Lookup the PTR for the Source IP -- this results in a Domain Name
2. Forward Lookup the Domain Name from #1 -- this results in an IP Address
3. The SourceIP of the incoming mail must match the IP Address resulted in #2.

There is sometimes an additional check of the SMTP Helo Banner, which is in the format of the domain name.  Do a forward lookup on the Domain Name, that results in an IP Address.  Then do a reverse Lookup of the PTR of the IP address, and that should resolve back to the same Domain Name in the SMTP DNS records above are set.

**But what if you have 30 mail servers, all sharing 3 different IPs.  How do you set the SMTP Banner, A Records, and PTR records to pass all the tests above?**  Assume there is no way for the 30 mail servers to know what IP address they are getting on the outside.  Each new TCP connection could theoretically come from a different Public IP.

My best guess, is you would have to set this up:

```
mailer.eddie.com     IN     A     1.1.1.1
mailer.eddie.com     IN     A     1.1.1.2
mailer.eddie.com     IN     A     1.1.1.3

3.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa.   IN     PTR     mailer.eddie.com
2.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa.   IN     PTR     mailer.eddie.com
1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa.   IN     PTR     mailer.eddie.com

SMTP Banner for each server:  mailer.eddie.com
```

But would that cause any other issues with 30 mail servers sharing the exact same SMTP banner?  And how would the Forward Look up (step 2 of 3 above) be affected if looking up the domain returns 3 different IP addresses?

To summarize, this is really a question that has three main tenants to be spoken to:

(1) Confirm the operation of the DNS/SMTP Three-Way check. 

(2) Confirm the solution functionality for multiple servers behind one public IP. 

(3) Confirm and Elaborate on the functionality of multiple servers behind multiple, non-static, Public IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Your NAT scenario *"Assume there is no way for the 30 mail servers to know what IP address they are getting on the outside"* is broken in the context of reliable SMTP delivery.

---

It's quite simple. A reverse DNS record can only reliable map back to one host-name. I.e. `2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` will only map to `smtp1.example.com`.

The same holds for the A-record: `smtp1.example.com.` should only point to one ip-address `192.168.1.2` otherwise you get a round-robin DNS where one lookup will show a different ip-address from the second.

(The recipient gets the incoming connection from 192.168.1.3 identified as smtp1.example.com and performs a DNS lookup that returns an A-record 192.168.1.2 --> Mismatch and thus extra spam score.)

That makes a simple rule: a mail-server should only use 1 single IP-address as the primary.